# In SCM, what is a Bill of Materials?

Tags: documentation, version-control

In reading about SCM (software configuration mgt, not supply chain mgt), I have seen mention of a "Bill of Materials" as a document provided with a build. What goes into the Bill of Materials document, and what is its purpose?

Is this a commonly used document?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming and should be asked on a different site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual contents and meaning of a SCM's "Bill of Materials" (BOM) depends on the tools being used and the shop. Loosely speaking they tend to be just a simple listing of the files used to build the system/product/component.

**The BOM cannot be complete unless it includes version information** on each of the files in it's list.

I have actively support SCM systems for the last 10 years and we never used this terminology. The place where I have seen the term "Bill of Materials" (BOM) used before was in Manufacturing, where it was meant to be all the physical parts used to assemble the product.

In the Hi-tech companies I worked with we used the same concept, *a listing of
version specified files used to build the software at some point in time.* In fact the listing of these files (with version numbers) were specially used to verify what portions of the product changed between releases.

Remember the version numbers, without these, the listing is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's an enumeration of each of the components in an installation module.

Answer (score 0):

SCM = Supply Chain Management? Software Configuration Management? Source Code Management? Please edit your question.

Regardless, a Bill of Materials generally referrers to a document that lists the parts and sub-parts that make up an "item" and if often a nested structure, that is, items are made up of other items, that are made up of still other items. The definition of item obviously varies from use to use, but by way of an example:

```
Car
   1x Steering Wheel
      2ft Leather
      1 horn
   4x Normal Wheels
      1 Tire
      1 Hub
      7 Lug Nuts
   1x Radio
```

In this example each of these lines are "items" but the Car item of made up of a Steering Wheel, 4 wheels and a radio. However, each wheel is made up of 1 tire, 1 hub and 7 lug nuts.

In Software Configuration Management the idea remains the same, but now you're listing the parts of software that make up the "package", and these software parts, may themselves have parts. Same idea, just a different defintion of "item."